# declare a xsl variable in a chosen to use in a other chosen

Tags: xml, xslt

I was wondering, can i make a xsl:variable

an then use it in a xsl:chosen like shown below(Dummy code. just to prove my problem)

```
   <xsl:variable name="variableValue" >
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$node/isTrue = 1">
          value
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           otherValue
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$node/this = 1">
           $variableValue
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$node/orThis = 1">
            $variableValue
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            $variableValue
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
```

i wanna do it like this, so that i don't need to repeat the code for every xsl:when i make.

as always. thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. This is what variables can be used for. To use the variable in this case, you can just do this:

```
<xsl:value select="$variableValue" />
```

Comment: What if the value of the variable is a css class. An you wanna ude it so. <div class="$variablevalue"></div> in the last xls:when ?

Comment: use attribute like before you close the div  <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="$variablevalue"/></xsl:attribute> or  <div class="{$variablevalue}"></div>